# Spring: couldn't autowire field - no beans of type found

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

I'm struggling this for couple of hours, but couldn't figure what is wrong with my settings...

Currently, in the `TestController`, the engine field is marked with the error

> "could not autowire. No beans of 'ServerEngine' type found".

I already tried to replace `@SpringBootApplication` with `@Configuration`, `@EnableAutoConfiguration` and `@ComponentScan` but still getting the error.

below are the relevant files:

Application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applictionContext.xml");
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

ServerEngine.java (act as the main system's singleton)

```
public class ServerEngine {

    @Autowired
    private DataLayer dataLayer;
    public DataLayer getDal(){
        return dataLayer;
    }

    @Autowired
    private UsersDal usersDal;
    public UsersDal getUsersDal(){
        return usersDal;
    }

}
```

TestController.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    ServerEngine engine;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void test(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){    
        engine.getUsersDal().addOrUpdateUser(...);
    }
}
```

applictionContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="serverEngine" class="partners.dataaccess.ServerEngine"/>

    <bean id="usersDal" class="partners.dataaccess.UsersDal"/>
    <bean id="dataLayer" class="partners.dal.DataLayer">
        <constructor-arg name="username" value="..."/>
        <constructor-arg name="password" value="..."/>
        <constructor-arg name="url" value="..."/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: Spring Boot doesn't activate XML configurations by default. Either manually import it via your `Application` class or (preferably) use JavaConfig. Just adding `@Component` to your `ServiceEngine` would be sufficient.

Comment: @chrylis, now the error is gone, but when I ran the Application i'm getting the following error "Field dataLayer in ....dataaccess.ServerEngine required a bean of type '....dal.DataLayer' that could not be found."

Comment: Because you still defined *that* one in XML?

Comment: So what should I do?

Comment: Get rid of *all* the XML and use JavaConfig exclusively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `main`, you're instantiating an `ApplicationContext applicationContext`, but then you do nothing with it - you don't pass it to the `SpringApplication`.

I'm not familiar with Spring Boot, but I see no place in your code in which the XML config's name is given to the `SpringApplication` either. So it probably only uses annotation config.

And finally, since `ServerEngine` isn't annotated with `@Service`, it won't be instantiated as a Spring bean during component-scan.

Comment: How do I pass the applicationContext to the SpringApplication? any alternative suggestion to the SpringBoot that can be easier to implement?

Comment: Perhaps adding [`@ImportResource("applictionContext.xml")`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ImportResource.html) annotation to the `Application` class in addition to `@SpringBootApplication` would do, and drop the manual context creation.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and best solution would be to annotate the classes that you are autowiring in you application like ServerEngine, UsersDal and DataLayer with the annotation @Service or @Component. If you do that, you don't have to explicitly create beans for them in xml or java configurations.